# Lenovo s10-3 doesn't wake from suspend

Tags: suspend, lenovo

I know some similar questions have been asked here before, and I have used Google, but none of the methods I've found have worked for me.

I was really seriously thinking about switching to Ubuntu on my netbook (I can't do it on my desktop, I use professional tools and I'm also a gamer) but I also need that function to live.

It just suspends and then when I try to wake it, the power battery and HDD lights turns on, then HDD disappears and it is stuck with the black screen, the only way to exit it is by holding power button for few seconds or removing battery. I'm on 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: I was able to get several s10-3 netbooks suspending and resuming by running `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and then edit and save this line ---> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=3` on kernel 3.2.0-53-generic-pae

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/871891

Some s10-3 machines seem to work, others don't.